# auth0 node,js api check permissions

Tags: node.js, auth0

I added with success permissions to token that hits my API from my REACT frond-end.
ex:

*“scope”: “openid profile email”,
“permissions”: [
“approve”
]*

Also I am able to authorize users hitting my API endpoint with help of jwtAuthz middlewere.

But I also need to have access to permissions inside token so I can apply some IF THEN logic inside my endpoint but I cannot figure how to have access to read permissions in my Node.js code. The middlewere just denies access but I need to branch different calls to other APIs based on permissions.

Please if you can point me into the right direction, especially appreciated if you include some node/javascript pointers.

I would like to just read the content of the token as it already contains this information instead of doing another call to management API which adds latency, complexity, etc.

Thank you

Comment: Documentation may help? https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs/01-authorization#protect-api-endpoints

Comment: Also worth noting that, from a quick check on [express-jwt-authz](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt-authz#options) it appears that it just checks `req.user` (unless you have configured it to do otherwise). Maybe do your own custom checks on `req.user`